# Separation of netstandard and dotnet core

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, .net-standard

Our organization has build a .Net standard 2.0 dll using the dotnet Core 2.2 SDK. The library uses Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions which require the same version as the SDK. The library compiles fine, so we have a netstandard 2.0 library, right?

Our organization later realized that dotnet Core 2.2 is now out of support, but didn't have time immediately to go back and fix all the libraries to move them back to the dotnet Core supported version, 2.1. They're netstandard 2.0, so that's fine right?

We are now building a new asp.net project that is based on supported asp.net Core 2.1, and when trying to use this library we're finding we have to upgrade to 2.2 due to issues with compilation. Am I missing something here? Shouldn't a netstandard dll be independent of the underlying SDK that was used to create it?

Comment: You should post the exact errors you're getting. Also: you shouldn't start new work with .NET Core 2.1 now that 3.1 (which is a Long Term Support version) is available.

Comment: Please edit your question to include details on "due to issues with compilation". .NET Core 2.1's SDK can also compile .NET Standard 2.0 projects, so those issues can be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions from @mason and @LexLi I think I have managed to find my own answer, looking deeper at the error.

```
NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.
Install/reference Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.2.0 directly to project MyAspNet to
resolve this issue. 
MyAspNet -> MyNetStandard 1.5.4 ->
  Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions 2.2.0 ->
  Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 2.2.0 ->
  Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.2.0) 
MyAspNet -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 ->
  Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0).
```

The issue really isn't about .Net standard or the SDK. Really the issue is with the ASP.Net Core 2.1 dependency constraint of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>=2.1.1 && <2.2.0)`. Resolving the version conflicts by referencing the following libraries does allow the app to compile. But this solution relies on .Net Core 2.2.0 DLLs, which may or may not work or be supported with ASP.Net 2.1.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions = 2.20
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions = 2.20
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder = 2.20
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration = 2.20
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions = 2.20
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives = 2.20
```

Given that .Net Core 3.1 has been out for a short time, and it looks like various libraries still need updating (e.g. Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions latest version is 3.0), that may not really be a good option at this time. The options still are to either roll the dice with ASP.Net 2.2, which is now out of support, or go move the private library back to having .Net Core 2.1 dependencies.